# Why should one not whisper in Nandi's ears?

Tags: shiva, nandi

I visited the ancient Lord Shiva temple in the lane of Mahalaxmi temple in Mumbai, As I started whispering in the ears of Nandi, the pujari there told that me that we should never whisper in his ears and gave the following reason:"Sin would be endowed upon you if you speak in Nandi's ears as our saliva may get applied on the murti of which *प्राण प्रतिष्ठा* has been done". Does anyone know about this? Is it true?

Comment: I haven’t faced any issue in any of the temples I have been to. in fact in Lingaraj temple, bhubaneswar, there is a Nandi temple as well, where the priest specifically asked me to whisper in Nandi’s ears. That was when I came to know that we can whisper in his ears. I normally do not whisper though, I bring my mouth closer to the ears and speak in my mind what I want to ask or pray for. Eliminates spitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per our traditional belief it is true only if prana-pratistha of Nandi idol has really been done.

1. The prana-pratistha mantra consecrates the idol and it is believed that the deity becomes alive. So the deity's body is divine and sacred. Tantra says:

> pratimaasu silavuddhim kurvaano narakam vrajet, meaning the ones who thinks idols are stones go to hell.(Tantrarajatantra, page 615 and Kularnava-Tantra 12/45)

2. Anything that comes out from our body like sweat and saliva is thought to be impure in our tradition.

Whispering in  consecrated Nandi's ears has the chance of spitting to His ear.That will destroy the sacredness of the idol and it will need Avisheka again to get purified.

Thats why none except brahmins can touch the consecrated idols and they too have to take snana and pure clothes and aachamana before touching a consecrated deity.

Normally Shiva and Nandi idols can be touched by all the four varnas, but taking mouth very close to them can be restricted for the above reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had also visited this temple of Shiva near Mahalaxmi temple. The pandit told me and mom the same thing. It is because he stays inside the temple and thinks that no one else should benefit and only shivji should listen to him and his family. In many joytirlings of Shiv ji, it is allowed by temple of famous joytirling to say in nandi ears.

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: Hello! Personal experience is not considered a valid source on the site. Your last sentence is unclear. Do you mean to say saying in nandi ears is allowed in many famous temples and Jyotirlingas?